# Objects in Blender are not joining properly

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, export, external-applications

I have a model of a tomato plant that I am using for a game. I can't get the objects to join properly although I have tried a bunch of different things and different conditions for exporting. There appears to be only 1 object in the Bender outliner, but when I test the model in my game, and in this Open 3D Model Viewer which I have downloaded just now, there are clearly 2.

[image: 2 meshes in the 3ds file]

I am using .3ds for these non-animated models. I opened some of my other models in the same program to confirm that they have the right number of objects, so it is only this one model that has problems. I even have another version with flowers instead of tomatoes, and that one has the exact same problem.

Comment: *I can't get the objects to join properly although I have tried a bunch of different things* How are you joining the objects? What exactly have you tried? Please edit your question and provide more information

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if you have multiple materials assigned in Blender.  The .3ds format requires a separate mesh per material, other formats do not have this limitation.